# 15000ms TTFB waiting time with Nuxt and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I am experiencing a very long TTFB time, around 15000/17000ms with a GET request. This is happening only with one specific call, the rest are fine.

I started experiencing this only after adding Nuxt Auth and Laravel Sanctum. *The request remains in pending (under the debugger network tab) for around **10 seconds** before completing the request and giving the JSON result.*

Here is my **nuxt.confing.js**

```
export default {
  srcDir: 'resources/nuxt',

  ssr: false,

  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.APP_VERSION,
    title: process.env.APP_NAME || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://raw.githack.com/lucperkins/bulma-dashboard/master/dist/bulma-dashboard.css' }
      ]
  },

  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  css: [
    '@/assets/main.scss'
  ],

  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/vee-validate.js"
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
    '@nuxtjs/moment',
  ],

  modules: [
    'nuxt-laravel',
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'nuxt-buefy',
    'nuxt-fontawesome',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

  build: {
    transpile: [/@fullcalendar.*/,"vee-validate/dist/rules"],
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          fix: true
        }
      })
    }
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    debug: true,
    credentials: true
  },
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/dashboard/'
    },
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: process.env.API_URL
      }
    },
    localStorage: false
  },

  buefy: {
    materialDesignIcons: false,
    defaultIconPack: 'fas',
    defaultIconComponent: 'font-awesome-icon'
  },

  router: {
    base: '/dashboard/',
    linkActiveClass: 'is-active',
    middleware: ['auth']
  },
  fontawesome: {
      icons: {
        solid: true
      }
  }
}
```

**Nuxt page** (I put only the js code for convenience)

```
<script>
// https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-vue-js-full-calendar-example/
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sessions: [],
      todayDisabled: true,
      calTitle: '',
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [timeGridPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
-->>    resources: '/api/sessions', //the very long call
        eventDisplay: 'block',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        nowIndicator: true,
        locale: 'en-gb',
        timezone: 'Europe/London', // without this, after Daylight Saving Time the event goes 1 hour back
        headerToolbar: false,
        businessHours: [
          {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            startTime: '08:00',
            endTime: '20:00'
          },
          {
            daysOfWeek: [6],
            startTime: '9:00',
            endTime: '14:00'
          }
        ],
        slotMinTime: '07:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '24:00:00',

        expandRows: true,
        eventClick: (calendar) => {
          this.$router.push({
            name: 'calendar-id-sessiondate',
            params: {
              id: calendar.event.id,
              sessiondate: this.$moment(calendar.event.start).format(
                'YYYY-MM-DD'
              )
            }
          })
        },
        datesSet: (dateInfo) => {
          this.calTitle = dateInfo.view.title
          this.todayDisabled = this.$moment().isBetween(
            dateInfo.start,
            dateInfo.end
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Laravel Controller**
The component "Fullcalendar" runs a GET request through "*resources: '/api/sessions'*" which goes to the following code.

```
private function getIntervalTasks($s, $start_period, $end_period)
{
    $sessions = [];

    foreach(CarbonPeriod::create($s->start_datetime, "$s->interval_num $s->interval_type_human", $s->end_datetime) as $start_session) {

      if (Carbon::parse($start_session)->between($start_period, $end_period)) {

        $canceled = false;

        if ($s->exceptions->isNotEmpty()) {
          foreach ($s->exceptions as $e) {
              if (Carbon::parse($e->datetime)->toDateString() === $start_session->toDateString()) {
                if($e->is_canceled) {
                  $canceled = true;
                  break;
                } elseif ($e->is_rescheduled) {
                  $start_session = Carbon::parse($e->datetime);
                }
              }
            }
        }

        if ($canceled) {
          continue;
        }

        $end_session = Carbon::parse($start_session)->addMinutes($s->duration);

        $sessions[] = [
            'id' => (int)$s->id,
            'title' => $s->client->name,
            'start' => $start_session->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'end' => $end_session->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'className' => $s->status_colors
          ];
      }
    }

    return $sessions;

}

public function index(Request $request) {
    $start = (!empty($_GET["start"])) ? ($_GET["start"]) : ('');
    $end = (!empty($_GET["end"])) ? ($_GET["end"]) : ('');

    $session_period = SessionPattern::has('client')
      ->where(fn($q)=> $q->whereDate('start_datetime', '<=', $start)->orWhereDate('end_datetime',   '>=', $end)
        ->orWhereBetween(DB::raw('date(`start_datetime`)'), [$start, $end])
        ->with('exceptions', fn($q) => $q->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(`datetime`)'), [$start, $end])
      ))->get();

    $sessions = [];

    foreach ($session_period as $session) {
      if($session->is_recurrent){
        foreach ($this->getIntervalTasks($session, $start, $end) as $s) {
          $sessions[] = $s;
        }

      } else {
        $items = ['none'];
      }
    }

    return response()->json($sessions);
}
```

ps: I also tried to see if the problem was with Fullcalendar. With a axios call, the issue continues.

Comment: i am troubling to get your codes logic in controller. What is `SessionPattern` model ? and what does the query do (it seems aggregate before/between/after time-intervels )?

Comment: how many records for SessionPattern usually returned?

Comment: Thanks for your responds. SessionPatter is the model for the DB table event_pattern. It includes all the record with the recurring pattern for each event. Sadly, the DB is very small and that model contains very very few records and it is already so slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering your question based on my similar experience.

But for accurate result i suggest to use **php profiling tools** like **KCachegrind** to find out which part of your code consumes more time to execute.

i Think The problem is With **Carbon** Which was Mine.

> Carbon Object Takes Long time to instantiate (is Slow).

i have refactored my code to not use carbon for date compare (make it in DBMS) and everything speeds up.

### The Probable Bottle Neck

I Think Your Problem is, you have fetched a lot of records from DB, and loop over them with foreach :

```
foreach ($this->getIntervalTasks($session, $start, $end) as $s) {
          $sessions[] = $s;
        }
```

then in `getIntervalTasks` you have a second loop :

```
foreach(CarbonPeriod::create($s->start_datetime, "$s->interval_num $s->interval_type_human", $s->end_datetime) as $start_session) {
```

it make the request execution in order of N*M .

```
Carbon::parse($start_session)->between($start_period, $end_period)
```

the above code `Carbon::parse()` is the slow code which is running in N*M (second degree) times.

### Probable Solution

I Think Your Solution will be to **Avoid Creating Carbon Object In This Order**.

Implement Your Business Logic (Time Compare Logic) In **DBMS** (With *Store Procedure* Or *DB Function*) Would Solve The TTFB Issue.

### Hypothesis Test

place this

```
$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($session_period as $session){
    ...
}
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;

return response()->json(array_merge($sessions, $time_elapsed_secs);
```

you can find the time consuming code section using this technique.

and obviously test if my suggestion was correct or not.

NOTE: returning `$time_elapsed_secs` is in **micro second**.

Comment: Would you say that it could be the combination between Carbon and too many loops?

Comment: Yeap, i think so. you can test my hypothesis with a profiling tool (KCachegrind). or measure execution time with `microtime` .

Comment: i have updated my answer and include **Hypothesis Test** Secion